# Issue on tab index from text box to another

Tags: php, jquery, tabs, row, tabindex

```
<td><input type="text" tabindex="4" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" id="productList" class=" form-control autocomplete_txt" required="" ></td>
<td><input type="text" tabindex="5" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required="required"></td>
<td><input tabindex="6" type="text" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="inputs1 form-control changesNo groupOfTexbox" autocomplete="off" onpaste="return false;" required="required" onchange="create_row();"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice total_alone" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required="required" readonly=""></td>



$(document).on('change', '.amount', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    if( event.which == 9 ) {

        create_row();
    }
});

function create_row()
{

    var tabindex1 = parseInt($("#tabindex_value").val());
    var i=$('table tr').length;
    var tabindex2 = tabindex1 + 1;
    var tabindex3 = tabindex1+2;
    var tabindex4 = tabindex1+3;
    var tabindex5 = tabindex1+4;
    var tabindex6 = tabindex1+5;
    var tabindex7 = tabindex1+6;

    html = '<tr>';
    // html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';

    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputss form-control autocomplete_txt" tabindex="7" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" id="productList"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control changesNo" tabindex="'+tabindex2+'" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" tabindex="'+tabindex3+'" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="amount form-control changesNo groupOfTexbox" autocomplete="off" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" tabindex="'+tabindex4+'" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice total_alone" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>';
    html += '<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" id="delete'+i+'" style="padding:0px 5px"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:#fff;font-size:14px"></i></a></td>';

    html += '</tr>';

    $("#tabindex_value").val(tabindex7);

    $('table').append(html);  
    $(".item2").autocomplete({
        source: "https://www.duminex.com/product/search",
        select: function( event, ui ) {        
            var a = i - 1;
            $('#id').val(ui.item.id);       
            $('#price_' + a).val(ui.item.price);
        }
    });
    i++;
}
```

In above code, On change some amount in textbox on press tab it will point next index 7 that is in newly created row. But dont know what mistake I made in code.After change amount in textbox if I press tab its not pointing to itemname.
Please anyone help me to get out of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a working example of your problem so that people can understand it easily. use jsfiddle or SO javascript editor for this purpose:- https://prnt.sc/h8m6hc  . edit your question and do that

Comment: @Kavya Shree: Your existing HTML markup at the beginning of your question was lost due to a formatting issue. My edit will make them visible.

Comment: yes now its visible., now thanks